# How can I pass the DrawableId parameter to XML Layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview

I have an layout item.xml like this:

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src=""
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Image view's src must come from include parameter like "@drawable/icon":

```xml
<include
   layout="@layout/item"
   app:drawableIdParameter="@drawable/icon"/>
```

How can I pass drawable id parameter to layout?

Comment: `android:src="@drawable/icon"` in ImageView, ImageButton etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your item.xml add the variable of type `Drawable`:

```
<data>
    <import type="android.graphics.drawable.Drawable" />
    <variable
        name="drawableIdParameter"
        type="Drawable"/>
</data>
```

Access the variable in the `ImageView` as:

```
android:src="@{drawableIdParameter}"
```

Now pass the parameter in the following way:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/item"
    app:drawableIdParameter="@{@drawable/icon}"/>
```